# Scrolling with no borders using android java

Tags: java, android, xml

I want to make a layout in my `android` app using `ScrollView` such that the borders of my `scrollview` items does not change their shape while scrolling. Please refer to the screenshots below.

[When screens loads](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yuokk.png)

[When I start scrolling the scrollview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2EYyc.png)

You can notice that for each `scrollview` item, I have round top corners but when I start scrolling those top corners gets behind the above view and gives the whole `scrollview` a box shaped on the top (screenshot 2). What I want to do is that when I start scrolling, `scrollview` should have round corners at the top all the time to avoid that box-shaped look and feel at the top.

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="20dp"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        style="@style/TextAppearance.MaterialComponents.Headline5"
        android:layout_width="140dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Discover New Flavors"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:text="CATEGORIES"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@drawable/meal_detail_radius"
                android:backgroundTint="#FF8B0C"
                android:padding="10dp">

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                    android:text="Burgers"
                    android:textColor="@color/white"
                    android:textSize="18sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="100dp"
                    android:layout_height="100dp"
                    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                    android:src="@drawable/burger" />
            </RelativeLayout>

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="-25dp"
                android:background="@drawable/meal_detail_radius"
                android:backgroundTint="#39BDF6"
                android:padding="10dp">

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                    android:text="Wraps"
                    android:textColor="@color/white"
                    android:textSize="18sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="100dp"
                    android:layout_height="100dp"
                    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                    android:src="@drawable/burger" />
            </RelativeLayout>

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="-25dp"
                android:background="@drawable/meal_detail_radius"
                android:backgroundTint="#B35CC6"
                android:padding="10dp">

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                    android:text="Drinks"
                    android:textColor="@color/white"
                    android:textSize="18sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="100dp"
                    android:layout_height="100dp"
                    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                    android:src="@drawable/burger" />
            </RelativeLayout>
            
        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>


</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Give a background to your parent layout as well, which looks like this

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="20dp"
    android:orientation="vertical"                
    android:background="@drawable/meal_detail_radius">
```

Maybe it works!